# where absence of string in a log file, send email. validating inputs

Tags: shell-script

The following bash script attempts to read a file and search for the given string.
*in this instance, the case should generate a positive result*
In case of zero length, i.e. the string is not found, then send an email using Postfix (as send-only).

```
#!/bin/bash

results=$(grep "Parameters: {\"id_at_chain\"=>\"001142\", \"articles\"" ~/makt/current/log/production.log)
lines=($results)
if [ -z "$results" ]; then
  echo "array articles 001142 missing" | mail -s "problem 001142" me@mydom.com techie@mydom.com
fi
```

What I want to do is put some verification code in order to test (and possibly dump to a log file):
• whether the file is found
• whether `$results` exists
• the length of `$results`

I can `echo $results` and it gives the expected result, however
`echo -z "$results"`  seems to output `$results` not the length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you think `[` is some shell syntax, rather than it being a command. Another way to write your code is to say

```
if test -z "$results" ; then
```

and then it might be more obvious that `-z` is a flag to the `[` or `test` command.

You get the output of the `grep` command into a string called `results`, and you then create a one element array called `lines` which contains this string. Presumably you have some plan for `lines` but at the moment it is just a distraction.

As for your bullet points

- `[ -e ~/makt/current/log/production.log ]` can tell you if the file exists
- `$results` always exists, it might be empty of course but you create it.
- `${#results}` is the number of characters in `$results`